# Enum values are not persisted as EnumType.STRING but as ORDINALvalue for child entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Enum values are not persisted as EnumType.STRING but as EnumType.ORDINAL value for child entity while using Spring JPA

I have Employee entity that has name, ENUM field and one-to-many association of address (child) entities. When the Employee entity is saved, the enum field on parent entity is persisted as String (as expected), but the enum field in child entity is persisted as ordinal value, though i used @Enumerated EnumType.STRING in parent as well as child entities.

My entities are

```
Employee.java

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", schema = "schema_emp")
public class Employee {

    public enum Status {
        PROJECT,
        BENCH;
    }
    private String _name;   
    private Status _status;
    private Map<EmployeeAddress.Type, EmployeeAddress> _addresses;

    protected Employee () {
    }

    @Column(name = "employee_name", nullable = false)
    public String getName() {
        return this._name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "status_text", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    public Status getStatus() {
        return this._status;
    }

    protected void setStatus(Status status) {
        this._status= status;
    }

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "address_type_name")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    public Map<EmployeeAddress.Type, EmployeeAddress> getAddresses() {
        return _addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(Map<EmployeeAddress.Type, EmployeeAddress> addresses) {
        _addresses = addresses;
    }
}

EmployeeAddress.java    

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_address", schema = "schema_emp")
public class EmployeeAddress {

public enum Type {
        PRIMARY,
        BILLING,
        MAILING,
        SHIPPING;
    }

private Employee _employee;
private Type _type;
private String _line1;

protected EmployeeAddress() {
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
public Employee getEmployee() {
return _employee;
}

public void setEmployee(Employee employee) {
        _employee = employee ;
}

@Column(name = "address_type_name", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@NotNull
public Type getType() {
    return _type;
}

public void setType(Type type) {
        _type = type;
}

@Column(name = "address_line_1")
public String getLine1() {
    return _line1;
}

public void setLine1(String line1) {
        _line1 = line1;
}

}

My service method 

Employee entity = populateEntity(resource);
new Employee .Builder<>().buildAddresses(resource.getAddresses(), entity);
return _repository.saveAndFlush(entity);
```

When I check the DB, one row is created in Employee table as expected and appropriate number of rows are created in employee_address table

In employee table, status_text field is ACTIVE but 
In employee_address table, address_type_name is 0 and 3 (i.e ORDINAL value)

So how to store the ENUM values as String on child table i.e employee_address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to define a Converter class and apply it automatically on type field in child entity

Converter code:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class AddressTypeConverter implements AttributeConverter<Type, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Type type) {
            return type.name();
        }

    @Override
    public Type convertToEntityAttribute(String typeStr) {
        return Type.valueOf(typeStr);
    }
}
```

and its usage in EmployeeAddress class:

```
@Column(name = "address_type_name", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = AddressTypeConverter.class)
@NotNull
public Type getType() {
    return _type;
}
```